# Android: EditText displayed with black background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, background-color, android-styles

I have a row with two EditTexts and two ImageButtons. In the preview of android studio everything looks fine and the EditTexts have the default style. But if I display it on my tablet the background is black.

How it should look like:
[image]

How it looks like on the tablet: 
[image]

Other EditText-Boxes are displayed correctly. 
Does anyone know why the these look different and how I can fix it?

Here the XML-Layout of this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/first_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/second_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.4"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/first_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:src="@drawable/move"
    android:background="@drawable/first_button_background"
    android:onClick="onFirstButtonClicked"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/second_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:src="@drawable/trash"
    android:background="@drawable/second_button_background"
    android:onClick="onSecondButtonClicked"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
I tried changing the background color to white but then the EditTexts lose their whole style so also the underlining will not be displayed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

this's because the editext default background change based on device theme go for an edittext with custom background and in a simple way include `android:background="#ffffff"` for your editexts

Comment: i thought about it to use a custom theme but I thought there must be a possibility to display them with the default style because other EditTexts are displayed correctly

Comment: i THINK A CUSTOM BACKGROUND IS GOOD AND THIS MAKE THE EDITTEXT LOOK SIMILAR IN ALL DEVICES  :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be occurring due to the imageButtons but You can change the background color of the edittext like this:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: thx for your answer. but when i change the background color to white also the whole style of the EditText changes. So also the underline disappears.

Comment: @e_card did you tried changing the color of the imageButton images ?
try that if it had any effect then they are the cause of the problem

Comment: I changed the color of the images to white but it didn't change anything with the EditTexts. I also removed them completely and they still stayed black.

Comment: @e_card I just tried your code in my emulator and it's working fine here. May be it is due to the background theme or so ?

Comment: i don't think so. because other EditTexts on the same fragment are displayed with white background

Answer (score 0):

May be your tab does not support the selected theme, try to change background color of your edittext using:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

if problem does not solve, then you can change background of edittext programmatically like this:

```
youeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```